# Trying to refresh parent page

Tags: javascript

**Problem statement:** I am trying to refresh the parent page from the child page on click of windows close button (top right).

The problem is when there is an error I am redirecting from the child page to error page. Now I close the error page, the parent page has to be loaded. Which does not happen because parent is missing.

But I open the child page with `window.open`.  The error page is opened by redirecting from action when an error occurs.

Can someone please help me crack this?

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: window.open(url,"","width=800,height=500,toolbar=no,dependent=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,menubar=no,location=no,statusbar=no,fullscreen=no");

Comment: window.open(url,"","width=800,height=500,toolbar=no,dependent=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,menubar=no,location=no,statusbar=no,fullscreen=no"); this opens a child pop up. from child we show a new page. from the new page we close the pop up, we have to refresh the parent page before the child pop up

Comment: Please edit the original post and add the sample code.  I also suggest reworking your question by providing more context about the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java? From your description you are only using client-side JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to answer due to the vagueness and absence of code, so please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

You have a parent page (say page1) and from there you are opening another window/page (say page2) and when you close page2, rather when you click on the close button but before it is closed, you want to refresh the parent page1.

If this above understanding is correct then I can suggest add a `window.onbeforeunload` function for page 2, and in it call the function:

```
window.parent.location.reload()
```

Explanation: `window.onbeforeunload` is called before the window is closed and the function above gets the parent of the current(page2) window (which is page1) gets its location, and then refreshes it.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:seems my understanding was a bit off. You want to refresh the first page from the other error page. If that is so then you can try and save a reference of the `window` object of the first one, pass it to the second one, and on the second page use that saved window object and do a `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: How do we save the reference of the window.open?

Comment: `var myWindow = window.open(url,"","width=800,height=500")`